# unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-api

Ive been trying to use the 'github_api' gem in order to pull in information. When i test everything in the terminal it all works, i am able to save information to my users and repos db that i have created. However, I put all the information in my controller and now i keep getting getting a syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' error. Below is the the code from my users controller and a picture of the error. Please help!

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @users = User.all
end

def create
    @user = User.new
        (   
        id: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].id, 
        username: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].login, 
        html_url: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].html_url, 
        avatar_url: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].avatar_url
        )
        end

    if @user.save  
        Github.repos.list user: params[:name] do |repos|
        Repo.create
        (
            user_id: repos.owner.id, 
            name: repos.name, 
            address: repos.full_name
        )
        end
        redirect_to users_path
    else
        render users_path
    end
end

def show
    @user = User.find(id: params[:id])
end
```

end

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating new user write parentheses on the same line and no need for `end`:

```
@user = User.new(   
    id: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].id, 
    username: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].login, 
    html_url: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].html_url, 
    avatar_url: Github.search.users(params[:name]).items[0].avatar_url
)
```

And it's better to use parentheses if you don't know where you can avoid them:

```
if @user.save  
  Github.repos.list(user: params[:name]) do |repos|
    Repo.create(
        user_id: repos.owner.id, 
        name: repos.name, 
        address: repos.full_name
    )
  end
  redirect_to users_path
else
  render users_path
end
```